# Is there a programming language which allows the redefinition of numbers?

Tags: programming-languages, flexibility

My first stab at this problem was in C

```
#define 2 5
assert(2+2 == 10);
```

Unfortunately

```
error: macro name must be an identifier
```

I also tried Scheme

```
(define 2 5)
```

but

```
can't define a non-symbol: (define 2 5)
```

I was wondering if there are any programming languages where this is possible.

Comment: Just a thought, but in C++ it might be possible to overload the `+` operator and then redefine how each operand behaves during addition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: that's difficult since `2 + 2`, for example, is a compile time evaluable constant expression. I don't see a way of doing this in standard C++.

Comment: Why are you asking? To know which languages to avoid?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's a neat idea. Unfortunately I don't think you can overload operators for builtin types like int. I tried to define a class, overload `+`, `int` operators on that and then cast the numeric literals to that new class. Which gives code that looks looks like `(T)2 + (T)2 == 5`. Which looks pretty weird and suspicious, but cool thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I sincerely hope not.

But that said, I do know of a way in Java: you can use *reflection* to adjust the values of the cached boxed `Integer`s: a JVM must cache all values in the range -128 to +127, and there does exist a mechanism to adjust the numeric values in that cache!

See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5/28818#28818 for more details. Here's the code in full:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class cache = Integer.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
        Field c = cache.getDeclaredField("cache");
        c.setAccessible(true);
        Integer[] array = (Integer[]) c.get(cache);
        array[132] = array[133];

        System.out.printf("%d", 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

The output is 5, essentially achieved by redefining the number 4.

Comment: I'm a bit resentful about installing Java but it worked. This is pretty cool, thanks for the answer.

Sorry, I don't have enough virtual stackoverflow points to up vote.

Comment: This is wonderfully horrific.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered hearing a story about this long ago, and today I decided to follow-up on it. That follow-up lead me to this question which unfortunately isn't exactly answered. This isn't exactly an answer, either, but ... here ya go.

I believe this can be done with [early Fortran compilers](http://computer-programming-forum.com/49-fortran/c1e8b7d194d9f46a.htm).

From that post (which is a copy of an original post to `comp.lang.python` which I haven't been able to track-down):

```
>     subroutine munge (i)
>     i = 3
>     return
>and then in your main program did:
>     j = 7
>     call munge (7)
>     write (6, 11) j
> 11    format ('j = ', i6)
>it would print 3!
```

The reason seems to be due to a combination of:

- Constant [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interning_(computer_science))
- [Fortran's pass-by-reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html) semantics

The compiler *interns* the constant value (`7`) and then calls the `munge` function with a pointer to the interned "constant" 7. The `munge` function changes the value of the passed-by-reference integer value and so now the *interned* constant value is 3.

So, this won't universally change the value of `7` to `3` across the whole program, but anywhere that interned "constant" value is used will now be using 3 as its numeric value.

This can be *extraordinarily* surprising (and rightly so, IMO) to younger programmers who have only dealt with languages whose arguments are almost always passed by value (unless otherwise specified). C, C++, C#, Erlang, Java, javascript, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. all use pass-by-value. For those languages, pass-by-reference semantics are achieved either using encapsulation (e.g. passing a mutable complex type such as an object) or explicitly passing a pointer to a value instead of the value (e.g. using the `&` operator in C and similar languages).